# How to create a new page with out navigation bar at the right side in Drupal 6.30

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

i have a website built using drupal 6.30. When i click every menu in the navigation bar, the sidebar at the right side gets visible by default. Now i had created a new page called Map.

```
(http://apfisn.net/Map)
```

When i click Map, i should not get the sidebar at the right visible in the page.

Comment: Drupal 6 has not been supported for years.
Don't expect anybody to answer any questions about Drupal 6 other than to tell you to upgrade/migrate your site.

Comment: There could be a JS event fired on menu click which toggles the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Context module for Drupal 6 from here https://www.drupal.org/project/context/releases?api_version%5B%5D=87
and install on your site, then follow the comment by Mark on how to sue Context to disable the sidebar region https://www.drupal.org/node/575822#comment-7157624

Other comments in the above discussion also explain how you can use your themes template files to remove a region.

You could also use a preprocess hook like https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/6.x in your themes template.php file and then add code to deteact you node type or specific page and then to remove a region.

I'm not sure why you are using Drupal 6, but I would strongly advise you to upgrade to Drupal 7 or 8.